# IntelliJ keys does not seem to work for UMLs

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to create Classes with UMLs using IntelliJ IDEA 13 Community Edition. I'm pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> but nothing seems to work on CentOs 6.2.

Comment: make sure that key binding doesn't bind anything on CentOS

Answer (score 0):

UML is only supported in the Ultimate Edition. Here's a page showing [the differences](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) between the two version.